# Razor page binding not working when loading via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-core

I'm loading the content of a webpage into a DIV using ajax. The page is a webform with a submit button for posting some updates to the database. After loading the page using Ajax it's not binding with the OnPost action, so it's not saving anything to the database.

This is the code of the Ajax script in my razor page:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#create_article").click(function (e) {
            $("#Content_DIV").load("/Arts/Branches/Create");
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

and this is the layout of the form loaded into the div:

```
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MSM.Models.DB.ReservContext _context;

    public CreateModel(MSM.Models.DB.ReservContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public MttoBranches MttoBranches { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.MttoBranches.Add(MttoBranches);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Is this a "normal" behaviour? How to make the "default" binding work ?
Thanks in advance
Felix

Comment: Sorry: Here I did not use Ajax at all, but anyway, the behavior is the same when using the java script "load" function and when I use an ajax call like this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit_but").click(function (e) {
    $('body').addClass('waiting');